# LayoutInflater with DatePicker Dialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker, dialog

I am trying to set an editText with a DatePickerDialog inside a .setOnClickListener. where, when the user clicks on the editText the DatePickerDialog will appear and then after the user selects the desirable date it will set it on the editText... something like this : [Android:DatePickerDialog on EditText Click Event](http://pastebin.com/FFHNX83D)

and here is my code [mycode](http://pastebin.com/FFHNX83D)

Any ideas how to do that?

I tried the above example and many more but nothing seems to work inside the .SetOnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText text;
private int year,currentYear;
private int month,currentMonth;
private int day,currentDay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

    // Get current date by calender

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay) {
                    currentDay = mDay;  
                    currentMonth = mMonth+1;
                    currentYear = mYear;
                    text.setText(mDay+"-"+(mMonth+1)+"-"+mYear);
                }
            },year,month,day).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I have store the user selected year, month, day in currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay respectively.

Comment: will this work inside the  .setOnClickListener? the form that the  .setOnClickListener calls is in a different layout than this one.

Comment: just use the DatePickerDialog showing code in **setOnClickListener()** method of EditText. It will work , i have tested it.

Comment: how to do this? anything i put from the outside is underlining them red

Comment: are u new to android? @GeorgeXReplay

Comment: pretty much @pial Kanti

Comment: you want to show datedialog when user click on **VisitDate** Edittext?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133110/discussion-between-george-x-replay-and-pial-kanti).